# How to iteratively (or most efficiently) create such list?

Tags: procedural-programming, iterators, iteration, functional-style

**Update**

A very crude attemp

```
myfun[n_] := Block[{PlaceValue},
    PlaceValue = IntegerDigits@n;

    If[
        FreeQ[PlaceValue, 9],
        PlaceValue[[-1]] = PlaceValue[[-1]] + 1,
        If[
            AllTrue[PlaceValue, # == 9 &],
            PlaceValue = Table[2, Length@PlaceValue + 1],
            PlaceValue[[First@FirstPosition[PlaceValue, 9] - 1 ;;]] = PlaceValue[[First@FirstPosition[PlaceValue, 9] - 1]] + 1
        ]
    ];
    FromDigits@PlaceValue
];
myfun[999]
myfun[299999]
myfun[22258]
myfun[2249]
myfun[2489]
```

as a function.

**OP**

I want to write a code that is able to iteratively create a list that looks like this:

```
l2 = Table[FromDigits@{i, j}, {i, 2, 9}, {j, i, 9}] // Flatten;
l3 = Table[FromDigits@{i, j, k}, {i, 2, 9}, {j, i, 9}, {k, j, 9}] // Flatten;
l4 = Table[FromDigits@{i, j, k, l}, {i, 2, 9}, {j, i, 9}, {k, j, 9}, {l, k, 9}] // Flatten;
desiredList = Flatten[{l2, l3, l4}]
```

That is, the next number is the smallest(first) number that all the digits are in non-decreasing order. I can manully do this for numbers up to 26 digits until I ran out of letters to use and then move on to use **double letter** for the iterators, but I am wondering if there is a better way to creat it? I want to use it for large number that has 60/70 digits and maybe even larger.

It can be a function that takes a number for example,

```
 f[344] = 345
 f[348] = 349
 f[349] = 355
 f[399] = 444
```

and

```
f[9999] = 22222
```

ect.

Or some kind of iterative formula that I can use in a `While` or `Fold` loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f = x \[Function] 10 x + Range[Mod[x, 10], 9];
F = X \[Function] Join @@ f[X];
result = Join @@ Rest@NestList[F, Range[2, 9], 3];
result == desiredList
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach is to define the function

```
f[n_] := Module[{c, d=IntegerDigits[n], e=IntegerDigits[n + 1]},             
    c=Count[d, 9]; FromDigits @ If[c==Length[d],
    ConstantArray[1, c + 1], e/.{0 -> e[[-Count[d - e, 9] - 1]]}]];
```

and then create the lists with code such as

```
ln[n_] := NestWhileList[f, 2 (10^(n+1) - 1)/9, # < 10^(n+1) - 1&];
```

For example:

```
ln[2]
(* 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 66, 67, 68, 69, 77, 78, 79, 88, 89, 99} *)
```